# Passing data from service to controller

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have created a service with the purpose of accessing an API. I need to return data to my controller but am unsure how to do this as I completely new to sails.

My Service:

```
// API call to get the ID of contact within Get Response with email address
getContact: function(options) {

    // establish connection to API
    var api = new getResponse(apiKey, apiUrl);

    var contact = api.getContactsByEmail(options.email, null, null, function (response) {
        JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });

    return contact;

},
```

I know the API call is working as when I log the response I get the correct response:

{"success":true,"data":{"error":null,"id":1,"result":{"sds":{"ip":null,"name":"Full Name","origin":"api","cycle_day":0,"email":"email@email.com","campaign":"id","created_on":"date","changed_on":null}}}}

My Controller:

```
index: function(req, res) {

    var contact = GetresponseService.getContact({email: 'email@email.com'});

    console.log(contact);
    return res.send(contact);

}
```

I want to retrieve the ID value but when I log the value of contact I get undefined. I think my problem is related to the scope but not sure.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are directly assigning a value from `api.getContactsByEmail()` which does not return a value.

By the nature of node.js, the function `api.getContactsByEmail()` gives you callback with the `response`. You have to get the value from within the anonymous callback function like this:

```
// API call to get the ID of contact within Get Response with email address
getContact: function(options) {

    // establish connection to API
    var api = new getResponse(apiKey, apiUrl);
    var contact =  "";
    api.getContactsByEmail(options.email, null, null, function (response) {

        contact = response;

        JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        return contact; 
    });

}
```

#### more ...

In my opinion, its better to return a callback instead of direct return of value.

```
// API call to get the ID of contact within Get Response with email address
getContact: function(options, callback) {

    // establish connection to API
    var api = new getResponse(apiKey, apiUrl);
    var contact =  "";    
    api.getContactsByEmail(options.email, null, null, function (response) {

        contact = response;

        JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        if(typeof(callback) == "function")
            callback(contact);
        else
            return contact; // return contact if there is callback func.
    });

}
```

You can use it like:

```
index: function(req, res) {

    var contact;
    GetresponseService.getContact({email: 'email@email.com'}, function(contactResult) {

        contact = contactResult;
        console.log(contact);
        return res.send(contact);
    });


}
```

Comment: Ah I understand. I think my problem was following the documentation to closely of the 3rd party node module used to access the API. It was assigning getContactsByEmail to the variable. Your solution is now providing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks like it should work, however I think you're running into an issue with this piece

```
var contact = api.getContactsByEmail(options.email, null, null, function (response) {
        JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

api.getContactsByEmail is asynchronous I assume, so this declarative statement won't work.

Instead declare contact and return it inside the callback, something like:

```
api.getContactsByEmail(options.email, null, null, function (response) {
        JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        var contact = response.contacts; //or however you access the contact(s) from the response variable
//You should also be watching for errors in your callbacks, but that's a different topic

        return contact;
    });
```

Read up on asynchronous calls in javascript and make sure you have a solid grasp on when data is accessible when using them.